# How to translate "they" when it is refering to a single company, group, or country?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

I want to translate this sentence:

> Nintendo announced that they would re-release the game.

Notice that "they" is used to refer to the entity Nintendo (or maybe the employees of the company). Would it be correct to translate it with "ili" in Esperanto? (Like in "Nintendo anoncis ke ili relanĉos la ludon").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually Esperanto prefers syntactical over semantic aggreement, hence as *Nintendo* is a singular, it should be *ĝi*.

However, there is no rule nor tradition forbidding the use of plural *ili* in such cases, where the noun is inherent pluralic (especially when the distance between the noun and the pronoun ist bigger).

Cf. [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/tria.html):

> *Ĝi* ankaŭ povas reprezenti unu-nombrajn grupvortojn kiel: *familio, popolo, armeo* k.s., kvankam temas pri personoj. Iafoje oni tamen uzas *ili*

Answer (score -5):

I would use the *si* pronoun, as its entire existence is for this use case. *Ĝi* is unambiguous in this particular sentence, but I'd imagine *si* becoming a necessity after more subjects get introduced.

"They" in English tends to be used in inappropriate places because there's either no appropriate grammatical construct or one just doesn't want to sound pretentious by being too wordy.

Comment: Sorry, but this is simply wrong. _si_ is a reflexive pronoun referring to any third-person subject/agent, itself it can never get into the position of the subject.

Comment: @CyrilBrosch I can appreciate the fact that my answer is wrong, but I now can't find an answer that seems correct. Literally any pronoun in the example sentence would cause ambiguity - due to the existence of two different subjects - and the ambiguity can only be resolved by context.

Comment: Context helps in most cases and languages, but there is also a common (though not universal) rule of constant reference, according to which the same pronoun in subsequent sentences refers to the same entity, and a change in subject must be marked explicitly (e.g. by a demonstrative pronoun like _tiu_). So I think there is less ambiguity than you think.